# Add warnings for cart items using filterContext nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

**Introduction**

I am working with newly added filter for shoppingcart/cart in nopcommerce.

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  bool IsShoppingCart = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].Equals("ShoppingCart")
                   && (filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].Equals("Cart")));
  var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
  if (result == null){return;}
  var model = result.Model;
//get model and add warnings for items in the model
}
```

> There are warnings passed along with the cartitems so it can be
> displayed. For example the "Product is deleted" warning when we add to
> cart the item and delete the product.

**Question**

I am trying to get a solution where i can add/edit warnings in filter and return the response. so my custom warnings being added to cart when exist. Custom warning can be anything with my business logic.

If someone have an idea, please help. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

I have been successful of doing it like below

var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
if (result == null)
{
return;
}

```
                                    var itm = result.ViewData.Model as dynamic;

                                    foreach (Nopcommerce.Web.Models.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartModel.ShoppingCartItemModel item in itm.Items)
                                    {
                                        if (l.Item.ProductId == item.ProductId)
                                        {
                                            item.Warnings.Add("new warning.");
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //update with modified entries
                                    result.ViewData.Model = itm as Nopcommerce..Web.Models.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartModel;
```

Please let me know if this isn't correct or have potential drawbacks. thanks